# HTML - Getting path to folder that current html file is saved in

Tags: html

I'm writing a help file in HTML named `send_message.html` that displays an image named `send_message.png`.

The `send_message.html` file and the `send_message.png` are both saved in a folder called `send_message`.

In the html file I have to include the path to the png file in order for it to display it.  I'm wondering if there is a way to get the path to the html file that I'm currently inside that way I can use that same path for accessing the .png file.

I want to do this since when people put this `send_message` folder onto their computer it will have different paths based off of operating system, user settings, people moving folders around, and other things.

This is a Windows based project incase trying to implement this on both Windows and Mac would prevent possible solutions.

I'm fairly new to HTML and thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify a relative path, therefore not including the folder path:

```
<img src="send_message.png" />
```

Comment: To clarify: in general, paths in HTML attributes are evaluated relative to the HTML file's location, unless they specify a domain, or start with `/`.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite There is also the possibility of adding a [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

Comment: I believe I understand the concept now, but I think I must have a syntax error? Changed from `<P><IMG SRC="C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSesame\plugins\send_message\send_message.png" NAME="graphics2" ALIGN=BOTTOM WIDTH=32 HEIGHT=32 BORDER=0>
</P>` to this with added in change `<P><IMG SRC="send_message.png" NAME="graphics2" ALIGN=BOTTOM WIDTH=32 HEIGHT=32 BORDER=0>
</P>` but now I just get a blank picture frame where the image should display.  Is this different than what you had in mind?

Comment: @Andrew_CS: is `send_message.png` in the same directory as the HTML file containing that HTML?

Comment: Yes, they're both saved in the `send_message` folder.

Comment: Also, just verified that both the HTML and PNG files have the same path of `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSesame\plugins\send_message`.

Comment: Just occured to me that since this HTML file is being called inside of another program maybe the program copys the HTML file, calls it from a different location, and that could be why the relative path doesn't find the image?

Comment: Turns out the open source software I'm using with this plugin copys the html file to another location.  You gave the correct answer to this question, thank you!